# Isn't it partial derivative?

Tags: calculus

Now I'm studying financial math.

This material gets me in trouble What I learned in partial derivative is like red written memo in the picture.

[image: capture]

However I couldn't derive the result using the way I learned.
So I guess It little bit different with partial derivative. (Is it outcome from stochastic derivative..?)

To derive those equation in the picture, ( under the line : 'Changing variables from S_1, S_2 to ξ we must use the following for the derivatives.' )
What study-material I should study?

Please give me some hint for those derivation.
Thanks.

Comment: It is partial derivative, written as a functional.

Comment: what is the 'as a functional' meaning? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a quick example to illustrate what the author is talking about. This isn't very formal, but let's suppose we have some expression
$$f(S_1,S_2)=\frac{S_1}{S_2}+\frac{S_2}{S_1}$$
Let's say we use a change of variable $\xi=S_1/S_2$. Then
$$f(S_1,S_2)=\frac{S_1}{S_2}+\frac{S_2}{S_1}=g(\xi)=\xi+\frac{1}{\xi}$$
Now notice that
$$(\partial_{S_1}f)(S_1,S_2)=\frac{1}{S_2}+\frac{-S_2}{{S_1}^2}$$
Whereas
$$(\partial_\xi g)(\xi)=1+\frac{-1}{\xi^2}$$
$$\partial_\xi g\left(\frac{S_1}{S_2}\right)=1-\frac{{S_2}^2}{{S_1}^2}=S_2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{S_2}+\frac{-S_2}{{S_1}^2}\right)=S_2\cdot\partial_{S_1}f(S_1,S_2)$$
Now since $$g\left(\frac{S_1}{S_2}\right)=f(S_1,S_2)$$
We have
$$\partial_\xi=S_2\partial_{S_1}$$
$$\partial_{S_1}=\frac{1}{S_2}\partial_{\xi}$$
This works regardless of the functions $f,g$ that we use as long as they are differentiable. I just think that having a concrete example helps in understanding.

Comment: Wonderful, now I can understand 'functional' in the above reply means. Thanks.